# Assembly MOV Instruction

Tags: assembly, buffer-overflow, .net-security

Hi guys im working on a CTF challenge and don't quite understand this asm command:

```
mov    %edx,0x20(%esp,%eax,4)
```

Im assuming its: move `$edx` into `(0x20 + $esp + $eax + 4)`

However when I checked this with gdb it isn't correct. Anyone mind explaining how this instruction works?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Intel syntax will make this clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AT&T syntax for x86 memory references goes like this:

```
displacement(base,index,scale)
```

giving the address of displacement+base+(index*scale).

That is, destination memory address for your instuction is %ESP+0x20+(4*%EAX).